# Why does this anonymous type not deserialize properly using JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType?

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I have the JSON string:

```
{"response":{"token":"{\"token\":\"123\",\"id\":191}"}}
```

And then I have the following code to Deserialize it, but it is returning null:

```
 var def = new
       {
           token = new { token = string.Empty, id= string.Empty }
        };

  var deserializedToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(token, def);
```

`deserializedToken` is null

Here is a more detailed example that I can't get to work:

```
var def = new
            {
                code = string.Empty,
                message = string.Empty,
                url= string.Empty,
                token = new {token = string.Empty}
            };

            var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(data, def);

            var innerDef = new { token= string.Empty, id= string.Empty };

            var deserializedInner = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(response.token.token, innerDef);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are two problems here, as far as I can tell:

- You don't have a `response` property to deserialize
- The "token:123 id:191" part is actually just a string - the value of the outer `token` property

So if you change your code to:

```
var def = new
{
    response = new { token = "" }
};

var deserializedToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, def);
Console.WriteLine(deserializedToken);
```

then you'll end up with:

```
{ response = { token = {"token":"123","id":191} } }
```

If you want to deserialize the token/id part as well, you can do that with:

```
var innerDef = new { token = "", id = "" };
var deserializedInner = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType
    (deserializedToken.response.token, innerDef);
Console.WriteLine(deserializedInner);
```

That then prints:

```
{ token = 123, id = 191 }
```

Comment: Okay so that explains the internalized question I kind of had all along. I've seen the deserializer skip *over* properties if it can find a match. Maybe better stated, I've seen it deserialize into objects that are lower than the root. If I had any more votes for the day you'd have mine; but that doesn't much matter for you probably. I'm sure by an hour in you're out of up votes. :D

Comment: I got it to work with your that example, but I put a more detailed on that I can't get to work.

Comment: @xaisoft: Well what's the JSON to go with that? To be honest, I think it may be worth asking as a new question, just to keep everything clearer.

Answer (score 1):

```
string jsonToken = @"{'response':{'token':{'token':'123','id':191}}}";
var def = new
{
    response = new
    {
        token = new { token = string.Empty, id = 0 }
    }
};

var deserializedToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(jsonToken, def);
```