# Why does this anonymous type with multiple properties not deserialize properly using JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType?

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, json-deserialization

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20123398/10263) previously, and now I'm having trouble with another similar JSON string.

Here is my JSON string:

`{"responseObject":{"code":"0","message":"HI","url":"www.abc.com","token":"{\"token\":\"abcdef\",\"id\":123}"}}`

Here is my code to dserialize which is not working:

```
var def = new
        {
            code = string.Empty,
            message = string.Empty,
            url= string.Empty,
            token = new {token = string.Empty}
        };

        var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(data, def);

        var innerDef = new { token= string.Empty, id= string.Empty };

        var deserializedInner = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(response.token.token, innerDef);
```

Comment: Just like the previous question, you don't have a `responseObject` property at the top level. And why do you not have an `id` property in the inner `token` message?

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: @JonSkeet - Sorry, not really good with all this javascript or json stuff yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had two major problems:

1. You weren't taking `responseObject` into account.
2. You gave the outer `token` the wrong type. It's a string containing JSON, not an object.

This works:

```
var def = new
{
    responseObject = new
        {
            code = string.Empty,
            message = string.Empty,
            url = string.Empty,
            token = string.Empty
        }
};

var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(data, def);

var innerDef = new { token = string.Empty, id = string.Empty };

var deserializedInner = 
  JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(response.responseObject.token, innerDef);
```

Answer (score 0):

Token is a string not an object. **"token":"**